# Configuring all Gradle JavaCompile tasks that are not for test code

Tags: java, gradle, configuration

I'd like to add some configuration in a Gradle build script for all tasks with type `JavaCompile` that are not for test code.  This is the best I've been able to come up with thus far:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  if (!name.toLowerCase().contains('test')) {
    options.compilerArgs += ...
  }
}
```

I'm not very happy with string-matching on the task name, though.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you have so many tasks compiling production Java code? Isn't it limited to just the task compileJava?

Comment: For Android projects there can be many tasks.  I'd like to write something that works across Java and Android projects.